# Why are my launcher icons missing/not working on a fresh install?

Tags: unity, icons

I just finished installing Ubuntu 14.04 and my desktop looks normal, but on the left-hand side where the icons usually go, mine were different! The Firefox browser wasn't there or any of the other icons that should be there as well. The only one that was there was the Ubuntu icon! When I click on it I see all the other icons like Amazon and Facebook, but when I click on them it says they're "disabled". I also can't access the web and it's very frustrating! Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you provide us some more details in your question about what installation media you are using and what hardware you installed Ubuntu on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about icons on launch bar, probably you have to find them yourself. Search for example 'firefox' using unity button left and up. Then drag the icon you want to launch bar.